# Program breaking block in sorting algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I'm writing a sorting algorithm for a linked list style program, where elements in the list contain CampSite objects. Getting the site type returns a 1 or a 0, where the 0 site needs to be at the front of the list. There's other factors required in the sort but none of them cause the program to fail construction. For whatever reason, this block in the sortList() method causes the program to never reach the GUI, despite IntelliJ saying the "Build completed successfully".

```
while (current != null) {
            index = current.getNext();
            while (index != null) {
                if (current.getData().getSiteType() > index.getData().getSiteType()) {
                    temp = current.getData();
                    current.setData(index.getData());
                    index.setData(temp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anybody help me understand why this is?

Comment: It's an infinite loop. If `current` is not null, nothing inside the loop makes it null. Then the same problem with `index` in your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have never incremented the `current` and `index` in the while loop, which will make it an infinite loop. Try to increment the value of index and current so that loop may exists.

Following code changes may help you

```
       while (current != null) {
            index = current.getNext();
            while (index != null) {
                if (current.getData().getSiteType() > index.getData().getSiteType()) {
                    temp = current.getData();
                    current.setData(index.getData());
                    index.setData(temp);
                }
                index = index.getNext(); // increment the index of the list
            }
            current = current.getNext(); // increment the current of the list to avoid infinite loop
        }
```